Why I can't change my version of node in WSL and VSCode?
I use this code for change my version of node. Why this is not functioning? Why am I missing? Help please!
seekeye@DESKTOP-TAAQNMD:~$ node -v
v18.20.2
seekeye@DESKTOP-TAAQNMD:~$ nvm ls
        v16.0.0
       v16.14.2
       v18.12.0
       v18.12.1
->       system
default -> v18.12.1
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> v18.12.1) (default)
stable -> 18.12 (-> v18.12.1) (default)
lts/* -> lts/iron (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.22.12 (-> N/A)
lts/fermium -> v14.21.3 (-> N/A)
lts/gallium -> v16.20.2 (-> N/A)
lts/hydrogen -> v18.20.2 (-> N/A)
lts/iron -> v20.13.1 (-> N/A)
seekeye@DESKTOP-TAAQNMD:~$ nvm use default
Now using node v18.12.1 (npm v8.19.2)
seekeye@DESKTOP-TAAQNMD:~$ node -v
v18.20.2
seekeye@DESKTOP-TAAQNMD:~$

Like you see above, the version of node it's still the same and I try a lot of things. What am I missing? And v18.20.2 it's already uninstalled, I don't understand....
nvm use
nvm ls
nvm force cache
node -v
